# Headless Chrome not detecting css elements

Tags: google-chrome-headless

I am finding headless Chrome does not seem to detect elements.  The following script does not work.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui  import WebDriverWait

options = Options()
options.add_argument("--headless")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)
driver.set_window_size(1024, 600)
driver.maximize_window()

driver.get('https://www.sportsbet.com.au/betting/soccer?LeftNav')

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".link")))
print('hi')
```

Change to not headless.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.set_window_size(1024, 600)
driver.maximize_window()

driver.get('https://www.sportsbet.com.au/betting/soccer?LeftNav')

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".link")))
print('test2')
```

Success!

I get for headless:

```
line 49, in <module>
    wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".link")))
  File "C:\Users\Django\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 80, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:
```

Change css: div:nth-child(1) > a > span.team-name.ib

I still get same error.  Why is it doing this?

Comment: Unable to open the url `https://www.sportsbet.com.au/betting/soccer?LeftNav`. Can you share the `HTML` please?

Comment: @DebanjanB Try a vpn or proxy.  IT could be you are region locked.  view-source:https://www.sportsbet.com.au/betting/soccer?LeftNav

Comment: This is quite strange.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It seems to redirect you if you are using headless browser.

Add:

```
user_agent = 'I LIKE CHOCOLATE'
options.add_argument(f'user-agent={user_agent}')
```

Now run:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui  import WebDriverWait

options = Options()
options.add_argument("--headless")
user_agent = 'I LIKE CHOCOLATE'
options.add_argument(f'user-agent={user_agent}')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)
driver.set_window_size(1024, 600)
options.add_argument("--headless");
driver.maximize_window()

driver.get('https://www.sportsbet.com.au/betting/soccer?LeftNav')

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".link")))
print('hi')
```

SUCCESS!

Answer (score 2):

Below mentioned configuration solved my issue.

```
    final ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    options.addArguments("--window-size=1920,1080");
    options.addArguments("--allow-insecure-localhost");
    options.addArguments("--headless");
    options.addArguments("--disable-gpu");
    options.addArguments("--no-sandbox");
    DesiredCapabilities caps = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
    caps.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
    caps.setCapability("acceptInsecureCerts", caps);
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with window size as the elements are not visible,
so setting minimum size to 600 makes it interactable/reachable

```
driver.set_window_size(1024, 600)
```

reference to user9045698